# Getting "Invalid secrets ownership" error while using chainlink functions on polygon mainnet

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to use chainlink functions on polygon mainnet with offchain-secrets, https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/tutorials/api-use-secrets-offchain.

While executing the same function on polygon mumbai, it is working fine. But when I am using it on the polygon mainnet, I am getting this error.

I am trying to run an algorithm to get the token prices of 4 different cryptocurrencies using Coingecko, save this data in a JSON file to IPFS and then return the hash/cid of this file to the smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

> While executing the same function on polygon mumbai, it is working fine.

Chainlink Functions is currently available on mainnets only as a BETA preview, so you need to apply for early access.